# jQuery min-height of section equal to windows height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set the min-height of each of these sections to the the height of the window. This is the current code...

HTML

```
<section id="hero">

</section>

<section id="services">

</section>

<section id="work">

</section>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$("#hero").css('min-height':($(window).height())+'px');
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#hero").css('min-height':($(window).height())+'px');
});
$("#services").css('min-height':($(window).height())+'px');
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#services").css('min-height':($(window).height())+'px');
});
$("#work").css('min-height':($(window).height())+'px');
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#work").css('min-height':($(window).height())+'px');
})
});
```

Comment: In what way is this code not working?

Comment: the jQuery does nothing to the min-height... I would the min-height to equal the window height for these 3 sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/dyZvY/)**</kbd>

```
$(function() {
  $("#hero").css({ minHeight: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $("#hero").css({ minHeight: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });
  });
  $("#services").css({ minHeight: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $("#services").css({ minHeight: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });
  });
  $("#work").css({ minHeight: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $("#work").css({ minHeight: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });
  });
});
```

or shorter version

```
$(function() {
  $("#hero, #services, #work").css({ minHeight: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $("#hero, #services, #work").css({ minHeight: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });
  });
});
```

for jQuery CSS you can use e.g

```
$("#element").css( minHeight, $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' ); // When you target single property
```

or

```
$("#element").css({ minHeight: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' }); // When you target single or multiple properties comma delmited
```

also you can use `'min-height'` or `minHeight`

Answer (score 1):

Changed `:` to `,`

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$("#hero").css('min-height': ($(window).height()) + 'px');
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('#hero').css("min-height", $(window).height() + "px");
});
$("#services").css('min-height': ($(window).height()) + 'px');
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('#services').css("min-height", $(window).height() + "px");
});
$("#work").css('min-height': ($(window).height()) + 'px');
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('#work').css("min-height", $(window).height() + "px");
})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You don't need for that jquery, just css please see here : http://jsbin.com/filoru/3

CSS:

```
section {
  width:33%%;
  float:left;
  display:block;

  height:100%
}
html, body {
  height:100%;
  padding : 0;
  margin:0;

}
#hero {
  background-color:red;
}
#services {
  background-color:green;
}
#work {
  background-color:orange;
}
```

html:

```
<body>
  <section id="hero">
hero
</section>

<section id="services">
service
</section>

<section id="work">
work
</section>

</body>
</html>
```